# Files in mysql data folder

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of files in mysql data/ folder

files are named

- `off.000001`
- `off.000002`
- etc.

What are those? Each takes 1.1 GB of space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are binary logs not transaction logs.

Binary logs record completed SQL transactions.

Transaction logs (specifically ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1) record SQL statements that are bulk committed upon transaction completion.

[sql_log_off](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_log_off) disables the general log, not the binary logs.

Binary logs are disabled by doing two things:

STEP 01) Comment out any line in my.cnf that has [**log_bin**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin) or [**log-bin**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin)

```
[mysqld]
#log-bin=off
```

It is easier just to delete log_bin or log-bin from my.cnf

STEP 02) You can either restart mysql or run this at the mysql command line

```
mysql> SET sql_log_bin = 0;
```

That's it !!!

From the name of the binary logs you probably have this:

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=off
```

That simply told mysqld to make binary logs named `off`

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the correction and +1 for the good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>They are the MySQL (transaction) logs. [This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/log-file-maintenance.html) contains all the details on them and information on how to clean them up. You can also disable these logs, if you want, by setting the [`sql_log_off` variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_log_off).</strike>

I stand corrected. I didn't research enough the answer I provided. Sorry for that. @RolandoMySQLDBA provides a good explanation for this question.

Comment: Yeah, i've found out myself, but those links you gave also helped. Anyway, I hope you don't mind if I reward correct answer to the guy who corrected you? :)

Comment: Of course I don't mind. He deserves to receive it! :)

Comment: Thank you kindly, to both of you !!! Hey, sometimes I get it wrong (Example : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21477/877)